# Why do I have to trim element text to check if it is empty?

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

My question is fairly simple but I didn't find any answer that corresponds to it yet, how can I assert that an element is empty with Cypress ? I just want to make sure that the element doesn't contain text.

My initial trial was

```
cy.find('.someElement').should('have.text', '');
```

But I ran into this error even though my div was empty in the DOM

```
expected '<div.someElement>' to have text '', but the text was '\n \n \n      '
```

I got it to work using

```
 cy.find('.someElement')
    .should(($el) => {
      expect($el.text().trim()).equal('');
    });
```

but I don't understand why I have to trim the text of the element.

Comment: Per [the documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find#Usage), `find` is required to be chained off a command that returns a DOM element, and cannot be used directly.  I suspect this should be `cy.get('.someElement')`, not `cy.find('.someElement')`.

Comment: An equivalent way of doing the same thing: `cy.get('.someElement').invoke('text').invoke('trim').should('equal', '')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some elements contain whitespace and some don't.  If you have a newline in your element definition, then it contains whitespace.

```
<div class='this_element_contains_whitespace'>
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class='this_element_doesnt'><span></span></div>
```

`trim()` is used to allow the first element to pass the test.